# Invoke python callable with an arg list

Tags: python, callable

Simple question: How can I pass an arbitrary list of args to a python callable?

Let's say I want to invoke a function from the command line, like so:

```
my_script.py foo hello world
```

with the following script:

```
import myfuncs
f = getattr(myfuncs, sys.args[1])
if f and callable(f):
    # This is the bit I don't know. I effectively want f(sys.args[2:])
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I must be overlooking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments). I.e. `f(*sys.argv[2:])`

Comment: Thank you, these things are always simple once you know what they're called, huh?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, check out the section [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the docs.

For your particular use, it could be something like this

```
def f(a, b, c): 
  print a, b, c

stuff = ['f',2,3,4]

f(*stuff[1:]) ### equivalent to f(2,3,4)
```